sched_getaffinity shows isolated cpus
I have the following code to check which cores my application is affinitized to:
#include <iostream>
#include <sched.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main() {
    cpu_set_t cpuset;
    CPU_ZERO(&cpuset);

    pid_t pid = getpid();
    if (sched_getaffinity(pid, sizeof(cpu_set_t), &cpuset) == -1) {
        perror("sched_getaffinity");
        return 1;
    }

    std::cout << "Process can run on CPUs: ";
    for (size_t i = 0; i < 32; ++i) {
        if (CPU_ISSET(i, &cpuset)) {
            std::cout << i << " ";
        }
    }
    std::cout << std::endl;

    return 0;
}

However, when I run this code, it does not reflect cores that have been isolated. I would have expected that because the core is isolated it would not be in the list of affinitized cores.
$ cat /proc/cmdline
BOOT_IMAGE=/vmlinuz-5.15.0-83-generic root=/dev/mapper/VolGroup-lv_root ro biosdevname=1 nosoftlockup processor.max_cstate=0 nohalt mce=ignore_ce idle=poll ipv6.disable=1 intel_pstate=disable intel_idle.max_cstate=0 rcupdate.rcu_cpu_stall_suppress=1 noibrs noibpb nopti mitigations=off isolcpus=11,13,15,17,19,21,23,25,27,29,31,33
$ cat /sys/devices/system/cpu/isolated
11,13,15,17,19,21,23,25,27,29,31,33
$ g++ main.cpp && ./a.out
Process can run on CPUs: 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25 26 27 28 29 30 31

My goal here is to have a function that given a pid, returns the cpus on which that pid is able to run on. I thought sched_getaffinity would do the trick, since the man page directly says this:

A process's CPU affinity mask determines the set of CPUs on which it is eligible to run. sched_getaffinity() writes the affinity mask of the process whose ID is pid into the cpu_set_t structure pointed to by mask.

Maybe my cores aren't properly isolated? Why does sched_getaffinity show cores that are isolated here?
